# Which platform should I choose for Advance Augmented Reality projects?

Tags: actionscript-3, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I made a project in Flash based Augmented Reality and played with it a lot and I wanted to move further in the field of AR(something similar to AR wearable glasses) in the future.I can advance further using Flartoolkit but one of the major issues that i was encountering was lagging while detecting multiple markers .
I have heard about unity and was thinking of developing AR using unity and ARtoolkit so is it worth to switch(for better graphic performance and less lagging) or is it also possible using Flartoolkit.I was using papervision 3d so maybe its a issue of 3d library I am using.

Comment: Too broad for SO, too opinion based. It depends entirely on what you want to do, what you're comfortable with and what you already can do/know. Please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the type of questions you can ask here.

Comment: Agreed with DodgerThud.  Any "Should I do x or y" questions are too opinion-based to really work with the Q&A format of Stackoverflow.  A discussion forum would be a better place to have this conversation.

Comment: I edited the question . Please check if its correct or i need to be even more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ask to to go for Vuforia and Unity for best experience.
Vuforia is working on mobile phones too. They have there solution for web based application also. If you want to target iPhone devices use ArCore.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually i have heard about vuforia and all the functionalities but I have also heard that all functions comes with a paid version and I as a student was making AR projects for my college.So considering the free version of vuforia , is it better than using unity and ARtoolkit?

Comment: Yes even ARtoolkit is good . When I was using Artoolkit the community support was not that much and if you are stuck you are pretty on your own. But now I am not sure but they must have improved. So Artoolkit and unity is also good option.  Have look here https://archive.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=6_Unity:unity_about